# Setting starting (left) bounding of X NumberAxis in LineChart

Tags: java, javafx, charts

I am having problems making my `LineChart`'s X `NumberAxis` display it's `Series`/`Data` starting from some left (starting) value.

[image]

As above: All my data is ascending for X axis starting with 50000. How can I make the chart also start at 50000?

I've tried: `xAxis.setLowerBound(50000);` but it didn't work.

Is there maybe some specific time this value should be set?

Additional note: `Series` is created along with `LineChart`, the data is added later over time to the Series (ascending order).

Comment: Did you call `setAutoRanging(false)`? Or just try `setForceZeroInRange(false);` (with auto-ranging on)?

Answer (score 1):

As said in @James_D 's comment `setForceZeroInRange(false);` worked.